# Get array data of a component to another component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have two components called '`ClickReportComponent`' and '`DateClickReportComponent`'.
and i have a array '`searchFields`' in '`ClickReportComponent`'.I need to pass  this array to `DateClickReportComponent` while clicking a `anchor` tag

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please share some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Subject / BehaviourSubject from rxjs to pass data from one component to other. Refer this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-zyqdak?file=app%2Fviews%2Fcatalog%2Fcatalog.component.ts) where i have passed an array from home/login component to category component. The 'next' method of BehaviourSubject will update the old value with the new value which can be subscribed in any components (Ref: category component).